# How to use templated class in constructor for a different class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have the following constructors for a class `vec` (vector math), which can be constructed using coordinates (`coord` class). The `coord`class is templated as I wanted both double and int `coords` for various reasons.

```
vec(coord<double> *start, coord<double> *end);
vec(coord<int> *start, coord<double> *end);
vec(coord<double> *start, coord<int> *end);
```

Is there a better way to set the constructors, such than I can have one constructor that takes all kinds of arguments?

Also, assuming this is possible, what is it called? Any research threw up little information

Comment: You can try what is called "variadic templates". This site and Google might offer a lot of information. Not sure if this solves your problem tho. You might also try "variadic functions", though some say it is outdated.

Comment: @CNomad Why are variadic templates required here? Why not a simple two-parameter constructor template? `template<typename T, typename U> vec(coord<T>* start, coord<U>* end)`

Comment: I dont think varadic code has anything to do with what i want here - i want to amalgamate the above three constructors into one

Comment: @dyp I understood from his request a way for him to use as much parameters as he'd like. In other cases, yours might be a much simpler and efficient approach.

Comment: @dyp does that require the `vec` class to be templated?

Comment: @Mauvai No, ordinary classes can have constructor templates, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes and class templates can both have *constructor templates*. Those are a special kind of *function template* that creates constructors:

```
class my_ordinary_class
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    my_ordinary_class(coord<T>* start, coord<U>* end);
};

template<typename X>
class my_class_template
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    my_class_template(coord<T>* start, coord<U>* end);
};
```

For example, if we create an object of the `my_ordinary_class` like this:

```
coord<int> s;
coord<double> d;
my_ordinary_class my_obj(&s, &d);
```

the compiler implicitly creates ("instantiates") a constructor that looks like this:

```
template<>
my_ordinary_class::my_ordinary_class<int, double>(coord<int>* start,
                                                  coord<double>* end);
```

The `int` and `double` are the template arguments deduced from `&s` and `&d`; they are used for the template parameters `T` and `U` of the constructor template.

For the class template `my_class_template`, we first create ("instantiate") a class, say `my_class_template<bool>`. Then, we can create objects of that class using its constructor template:

```
coord<int> s;
coord<double> d;
my_class_template<bool> my_obj(&s, &d);
```

The compiler will instantiate the class `my_class_template<bool>` and it will instantiate a constructor from its constructor template that looks like:

```
template<> // class template
template<> // constructor template
my_class_template<bool>::my_class_template<int, double>(coord<int>* start,
                                                        coord<double>* end);
```